# An alternative to MedCapture for the correct size of the images

Tags: images, resize, tools, image-format

I'm using an app **Siverapp** for the evaluation of the competences and learning of school pupils of every order and degree. This app use to insert an image the software **MedCapture** to capture the images at the correct size.

There is, into the app **Siverapp** an advice: minimum required dimensions of the image *324 x 242 pixels* (only in `.jpg`).

Is there an excellent online tool that automatically allows you to create images with the correct size to be used into Siverapp, without the need to install any software?

Comment: Software recommendations are generally too broad for the StackExchange format. You might be better suited on [SoftwareRecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ZachSaucier I'm not searching any software but an excellent tool on line to manipulate images optimally and faster. I haven't found any at the moment.

Comment: You need a web application which is powerful enough for creating the content you want to show. There are many services which can be good enough and can be run with common browsers. Try this https://vectr.com and this https://www.photopea.com at first . In Photopea you can paste PrntScreen -captures as a new layer if needed. The capture can be taken from elsewhere. If none of these applications is ok then tell in the question why they are useless. I guess very few of us have ever heard of Siverapp and even fewer know what special it needs. Maybe you should ask the seller and Siverapp users

Comment: Are you looking for screen capture software?   There are dozens of such apps. Just google it.  Why can't you install any software? What's wrong with the software you already have?

Comment: @BillyKerr people who work for bureaucratic organizations meet incredible difficulties. I have seen the same. We got  a web browser, MS Office and a system for in-organization messaging, orders and job control. That was all, any attempt to have something else was forbidden and prevented technically. It was actually a little more limited. The web browser reached only the intranet, no www. Having something else was possible only outside the fence of employers area.

Comment: @user287001 - yes I realise that, but still the OP doesn't mention was is wrong with the software already installed.  As for the installation of software in an organisation which restricts the installation of additional software, that is probably something that should be taken up with the organisation's IT department, especially if the software already installed is not meeting the needs of the employees.

Comment: @user287001 - note also that you can copy paste screen captures into standard software that comes with most computers, such as MS Paint for example, and even crop the image if necessary - so a web app may not even be necessary.

Comment: @BillyKerr another possible cause  is a must to try to use a continuously varying bag of computers, tomorrow something unknown today and probably else than the Android phone used today.

Comment: @user287001 Thank your much for your help and the suggestions of vectr.com and photopea.com that I have not known. Can you convert your comment, please, into an answer? Thank you.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi, and excuse me for my delay and the question. Into my old laptop since to 2004 (OS W7 32-bit, lower ram-originally it was Wvista Intel Core Duo inside) I have installed simple programs. I have not any smartphone and I use an old phone of the 2001. If I install many programs I think that my laptop not is very fast. You think that I use MikTeX that is very heavy. My best regards.

Comment: You could just take a screen capture, using the "PrtScr" key. Then paste it into MS Paint, then crop it to the size you need - MS Paint is already installed in Windows 7, so there's no need to install anything else.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you very much also for you, again. Can you convert your comment into an answer please? Thus I vote is and I remember better the answers instead to read the comments.

Comment: ok, have done so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web application which is powerful enough for creating the content you want to show. There are many services which can be good enough and can be run with common browsers. Try this https://vectr.com/ and this https://www.photopea.com/ at first . In Photopea you can paste PrntScreen -captures as a new layer if needed. The capture can be taken from elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much with a lot of sincerity.

Answer (score 1):

You could just take a screen capture using the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key. Then paste it into MS Paint, then crop it to the size you need.  MS Paint is already installed in Windows 7 by default, so there's no need to install anything else, or use a web app.

Comment: Done also for me :-) Thank you very much.